# why dont receiving data

Tags: java, android

I make an application that communicates with an optical device using Android in theory as Host UsbManager mode according to the repository: https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

I connect to an ABACUS A9U cable and it communicates with the optical device. He sent the bytes to write and they receive them, but when I request the reading of the response I receive nothing.

This is my code

```
 private void Conection(UsbManager manager) throws IOException{
    List<UsbSerialDriver> drivers = UsbSerialProber.getDefaultProber().findAllDrivers(manager);
    if (drivers.isEmpty()){
        Log.i(TAG,"Driver No Disponibles"+"\n");
    }else{
        UsbSerialDriver driver = drivers.get(0);
        Log.i(TAG,"Driver "+driver.toString()+"\n");
        UsbDeviceConnection con = manager.openDevice(driver.getDevice());
        Log.i(TAG,"Conexión "+con+"\n");
        UsbSerialPort port = driver.getPorts().get(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "Puerto "+port+"\n");
        port.open(con);
        port.setParameters(9600,8,UsbSerialPort.STOPBITS_1,UsbSerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        Log.i(TAG,"Numero Conexión "+ con.getSerial() +"\n");

        port.setDTR(true);
        port.setRTS(true);

        Log.i(TAG,"CTS "+ port.getCTS());
        Log.i(TAG,"RTS "+ port.getRTS());
        Log.i(TAG,"DTS "+ port.getDTR());

        String ss = "55";
        byte[] ss2 = ss.getBytes();

        int PW1 = port.write(ss2,1000);
        if (PW1 != 0){
            Log.i(TAG,"Escritura 1 "+ PW1 + " Bytes Escritos con valor de "+ new String(ss2) +"\n");
        }

        String Frame_Request = "EE0000000001201310";
        byte[] Frame_Request_B = Frame_Request.getBytes();
        int PW2 = port.write(Frame_Request_B,1000);
        if (PW2!= 0){
            Log.i(TAG,"Escritura 2 "+ PW2 + " Bytes Escritos con valor de "+ new String(Frame_Request_B) +"\n");
            Request.setText(new String(Frame_Request_B));
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG,"Error en Escritura 2 "+ PW2 + " Bytes Escritos con valor de "+ new String(Frame_Request_B) +"\n");
        }

        byte[] Frame_Response_B = new byte[14];
        int PR1 = port.read(Frame_Response_B,14000);
        if (PR1 != 0){
            Log.i(TAG,"Lectura 1 "+ PR1 + " Bytes Leídos con valor de "+ new String(Frame_Response_B) +"\n");
            Response.setText(new String(Frame_Response_B));
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG,"Error en Lectura 1 "+ PR1 + " Bytes Leídos con valor de "+ new String(Frame_Response_B) +"\n");
        }

        port.close();
    }
}
```

The output is 0 bytes read. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Are you sure that device support for android? Look at here https://abacuselectrics.com/usbsoft.htm

Comment: If your usb device use ftdi chip, try to use this code https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/Android_JAVA_D2XX_Projects.htm

Comment: The device is compatible, also add the GDP GDP to the library so that the library FTDI controller recognizes the device.

Type but can't use port.read ()

Comment: Are you have protocol communication to read that device?

Comment: If you have that protocol, please share your device protocol, so that we can find out what you sent the correct command to the device.

Comment: try to replace getBytes() with hexStringToByteArray

Comment: Are you sure the device speaks zoned hex? or should you be sending that hex as binary?

Comment: Some way to show the error

Comment: If you send incorrect command (protocol) to ABACUS A9U, that device doesn't response your request, even though your usb is already connected to that device. Please share documentation or manual book about "EE0000000001201310" (Communication protocol of ABACUS A9U).

Comment: Are you sure set the correct value for port, baudrate, data bit, stop bit, and parity?